# TL494 current limiting without current sense

Tags: power-supply, current, power-electronics

Is it possible to limit the current without using current sense feedback in TL494??
The TL494 have two amplifier both of them sensed only voltage (12V_A & REF) from buck regulator and TL494 limit the current to 20A.
I could not see the current shunt or sensor not used for feedback.
I could not understand how the current limiting without current sense as a feedback?? This is used for battery charging application. input voltage 55VDC (P+ and P-).
[image]

Comment: Yes it is possible but you are using both amplifiers already.

Comment: you would have to add the missing parts to pin3 with a diode.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer..I could not see the any connection involved in pin number 3.Attached (edited) complete circuit related to TL494. could you please explain how the current limiting is work. Also suggest if i missed notice any points.

Comment: I have no solution and only suggest how it could be done

Comment: Could you please suggest how it could be done ?

Comment: You will be wiser to learn how to search than ask

Comment: Yes I am trying to learn how to search.